# Filtering model results in empty array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following controller:

```
App.SkillsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init: function() {
        var store = this.get('store');
        var skills = store.findAll('skill');
        this.set('model',skills);
        console.log(skills);
        var tac_skills = skills.filter(function(item,index,self){
                return true;

        });
        console.log(tac_skills,'Tac Skills');
        this.set('tac_skills',tac_skills);
    }
});
```

The skills are loaded properly and the model is set correctly.  They even output into the view properly when I iterate over model, but for some reason tac_skills keeps coming back as an empty array, even though each item should be returned true.  I use filter in a few different locations in my app and it works great, but here, for some reason, it doesn't work.

Any ideas why?  Any assistance is appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure the skills are loaded before attempting to iterate over them

```
var tac_skills;
store.find('skill').then(function(skills) {
  tac_skills = skills.filter(....);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using a route/model hook instead of on the init of the controller to get the model.  The model will be resolved before it's assigned to the controller.  Then you should use a computed property for your tac_skills.

```
 App.SkillsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(){
           return this.get('store').findAll('skill');
      }
 });

 App.SkillsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      tac_skills: function(){
          return this.get('model').filter(function(item,index,self){
            return true;
         });
      }.property(), // add dependencies here where relevent, for example if the
                    // filter options settings are changing and you want to recalculate
                    // tac_skills
 });
```